# Gaussian elimination and NaNs as a result in octave

Tags: matlab, octave

I am a rather newbie when it comes to Octave and codes. I have an assigment to do about Gaussian elimination. I have to use a pseudocode that i cannot change whatsoever. I wrote this piece of code:

```
clc; clear all; close all;

a = [1 2 3 4 5;
     2 3 4 5 6;
     3 4 5 6 7;
     4 5 6 7 8;
     5 6 7 8 9;]

b = [1; 2; 3; 4; 5;]
n = size(a,1);

#Gaussian Elimination
for k=1:n-1
  for i=k+1:n
    a(i,k) = (a(i,k)/a(k,k));
    for j=k+1:n
      a(i,j)= a(i,j) - a(i,k)*a(k,j);
    endfor
  endfor
endfor
disp("a-----------------------")
disp(a);
#Forward Elimination
for k=1:n-1
   for i=k+i:n
     b(i) = b(i) - a(i,k)*b(k);
   endfor
endfor
#Backward solve
x = zeros(n,1)
for i=n:-1:1
   s=b(i);
   for j=i+1:n
     s=s-a(i,j)*x(j);
   endfor
x(i)= s/a(i,i)
endfor
disp(x);
```

However for some reason when checking how the script works I find that after first step "Gaussian elimination" matrix a starts containing a bunch of NaNs instead of numbers. I dont know how to fix it

I did try working with other codes, but as i mentioned it has to be the one above.
at the end it should return x = [x1;x2;x3;x4;x5] but instead it returns NaN  5 times.

Comment: This matrix is not invertible, so if you try solving the system `a * x = b` you will necessarily encounter a division by zero at some point.

Comment: And even if it was invertible, you are never testing for possible elements equal to zero. In your first triple loop you divide by `a(k,k)`: what does tell you that `a(k,k)` is not zero?

Comment: I checked... when `k = 3` and `i = 4` the `a(k,k)` is zero... So the division `a(i,k)/a(k,k)` doesn't possible... May be test if `a(k,k) = 0` could fix...